# Flask-WTF Dynamic radiofield is running a new query upon form submission

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am working on building a multiple choice quiz with Flask-WTF and SQLAlchemy that pulls random quotes and possible answers from a database table. I have been able to do just that. However, when the form is submitted and the chosen answers are saved to a new database table, I am seeing that the actual questions (quotes) and answers have been changed. It looks as if a new query is being run upon form submission. Here is a simple example of what I mean.

Actual Question on the Quiz with Options

Who said..."The sky is blue."

1. Frank (selected as the answer)
2. Harry
3. Anne
4. Mary

Data Saved to the Database

Question: Who said..."The apple is red."

Chosen Answer: Tom

I'm trying to figure out how to stop the additional query from happening so I can save the data from the questions the user actually sees and answers.

Here is my form:

```
    class Quiz(FlaskForm):
        q1 = RadioField('', coerce=str, validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[])
        q2 = RadioField('', coerce=str, validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[])
        q3 = RadioField('', coerce=str, validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[])
        q4 = RadioField('', coerce=str, validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[])
        q5 = RadioField('', coerce=str, validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[])
```

And my view route:

```
    @app.route('/quiz/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def quiz():
        form = Quiz()
        for field in form:
            if field.type != "RadioField":
                continue
            else:
                pulls = Quotes.query.order_by(func.rand()).limit(1)
                for pull in pulls:
                    answer = pull.speaker
                    option_two = pull.option_two
                    option_three = pull.option_three
                    option_four = pull.option_four
                    question = pull.line_text
                    field.label = pull.line_text
                    field.choices = [("1", answer), ("2", option_two), ("3", option_three), ("4", option_four)]
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            for field in form:
                if field.type == "CSRFTokenField":
                    continue
                else:
                    user_answer = field.data
                    question_id = field.id
                    question_line = field.label
                    correct_answer = answer
                    submission = Responses(question_id, question_line, user_answer, correct_answer)
                    db.session.add(submission)
                    db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('you_passed'))
        return render_template('quiz.html', form=form)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm also open to any suggestions about my current code. I'm new to Python and haven't reached the point of elegance in my coding. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the values coming through in field.data?

Comment: For each field (question) in the form, I have field.data set to the user's answer (user_answer). If I am understanding the flask-wtf docs correctly, the field.data for a radiofield is the choice that has been selected. In my case, however, the selected choice is not the one being added to the database. Is that what you meant by checking the values?